# JQuery DataTables - Cannot Access API

Tags: jquery, api, datatables

I am just trying to access the search() and draw() methods like I have seen in numerous examples. However when I attempt to access search() or draw() the intellisense acts as if they do not exist, and I also get errors in FireBug. This should not be this difficult to do, and I am not sure what I am doing incorrectly. I am utilizing datatables 1.10.7 so there shouldn't be a problem accessing the api methods.

I am aware of the difference between.

.dataTable() and .DataTable()

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rfjhy.png)

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What other examples?

Comment: Well, Visual Studio intellisense aside, does it *actually fail* in some way?

Comment: Currently in FireBug I am getting the following error stating "Too much recursion".

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call `search()` or `draw()` API methods in handler for [`search`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/search) event as they will cause recursion, because both method generate [`search`](http://datatables.net/reference/event/search) event internally.